# Switching content in LWC with radio group?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I have this [radio group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSaMA.png) which should work in that if I select the top option, the first two rows are shown only, and if I select the bottom option, the last row is only shown. How can I create this dynamic sort of tab selection within LWC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is documented here : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_conditional

This will looks something like this:

```html
<template if:true={topIsSelected}>
   <!-- first top two rows -->
</template>
<template if:true={bottomIsSelected}>
   <!-- last row -->
</template>
```